# Allow privileges links to be clicked without JavaScript

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design, hyperlinks, privileges-page

On a [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges?tab=all), each of the privileges are only clickable when JavaScript is enabled, even though they simply link the user to another page. Can we wrap each of the `div.privilege-table-row`s with an `a` tag and a normal `href`, and remove the JavaScript-only clicking?

Comment: Makes me wonder why this wasn't done in the first place. The inherited `<a>` styling could be overridden easily.

Comment: About wrapping `<div>`s in `<a>`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5320404/wrap-link-a-around-div.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This has been completed by [Sklivvz](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/131112/sklivvz) and was deployed earlier today. The privileges in the list are now html `<a href>` links.

Answer (score 7):

It really makes no sense this *still* happens! SE uses HTML5 (evident by their use of `<!DOCTYPE html>`), so it is, now, 'legal' to wrap an div with an anchor - why not do it?

The current technique, whilst clever IMO, is ugly; you cannot *copy* the URL without opening the link, and you cannot open the link in *a new tab*.

---

I've made a userscript to convert the annoying `div`'s to `a`'s (which, I might add, ***was* 'legal' in previous HTML versions...**, and style it so it looks just like a `div`. Whether that's the best way or not, I don't know, but it's better than it is now!

### [Install from Github Gist](https://gist.github.com/shu8/c727e0cc3d5bff23b51f)

If you're unsure on how to install userscripts, see the guide at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/tags/script/info)

A gif showing it in all its glory!:

> [image]

However, I really hope this, or the method written above, or any other possible method is implemented by SE soon - a userscript shouldn't be necessary to do this! :(

Comment: It's not needed any longer

Comment: @bluefeet yay +1! About time :P